# Changing hover to click for header navigation flyout menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, click

- Given: A simple header with navigation elements.
- When: A user hovers over a header nav element and a mini flyout appears
- Then: The user will have to click on the element to display the flyout

The code below works great for hover but I would like the mini flyouts to appear upon click instead of hover. When I change .hover to .click nothing happens.

Any ideas?

JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
function displayFlyout(main_id, content_id) {
    jQuery(main_id).hover(function () {
            jQuery(content_id).stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
            jQuery(this).addClass("fly-dropdown");
        },
        function () {
            jQuery(content_id).stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
            jQuery(this).removeClass("fly-dropdown");
        }
    );
}

displayFlyout("#example_one", "#example_one_content");
displayFlyout("#example_two", "#example_two_content");
displayFlyout("#example_three", "#example_three_content");
});
```

Html (Just one example of a flyout)

```
<ul class="header_flyout col-md-10 pull-right">
        <li class="contact_us">
            <div id="example_one" class="no-dropdown">
                <span class="menu"><?php echo $this->__('Example'); ?></span>
                <div class="header-dropdown-content" id="example_one_content">
                    <span class="blue-arrow">&nbsp;</span>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('contact_mini'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>.....</li> (example two)
        <li>.....</li> (example three)
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the the `.hover()` method accepts two parameters, [from the docs](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

On the other hand the `.click()` function accepts only one parameter, what you could do is listen to the `click` event on the document and if it hits the target you want you activate the dropdown, otherwise you'll hide the dropdown, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    function displayFlyout(main_id, content_id) {
    jQuery(document).click(function (ev) {      
      if (jQuery(ev.target).parent(main_id).is(jQuery(main_id))) {
        jQuery(content_id).stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
        jQuery(this).addClass("fly-dropdown");      
      } else {
        jQuery(content_id).stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
        jQuery(this).removeClass("fly-dropdown");
      }
   });
    }

    displayFlyout("#example_one", "#example_one_content");
});
```

You can also check it out on this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13v3swqg/).

Hope it helps,
Cheers.

**EDIT:** *Keep in mind taht using this solution meand that the target of the click will be the `<span class="menu">Example</span>` that's why I used the `.parent()` function to traverse up the dom to find the element you were intending to bind.*

Comment: Wow, thank you @Lucas Lazaro this is working great. Do I need to add more to the else statement in order to be able to click anywhere to close the flyout or would that be something different? Some boolean logic maybe? Currently, you have to click in the content_id to close the flyout. Thanks

Comment: @HawortDe No worries! Hmm... on my Fiddle it seems to work fine, clicking anywhere on the canvas will close the flyout, which browser are you previewing this?

Comment: I'm in a local Magento environment using Chrome. Your fiddle is exactly what I was looking for however, my flyouts are reacting exactly opposite. Testing for any conflicts now.